# I can't seem to import any non-standard library with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When I try to import any non standard libraries it seems fine, it doesn't show any error, but when I try to import, for example, pygame or django, it lists as an error

```
Unresolved import 'pygame'
```

[image: Unresolved import 'pygame' example]

The problem with this is that it doesn't try to complete the word when pygame is invoked, unlike when I invoke sys. I've tried updating the libraries and it doesn't help.

It still runs just as usual, without any errors.
This is a fresh install of VS 2019, python 3.8

Comment: I have never used vscode, i'm just searching for solutions with VS 2019

Comment: Never written Python, never compiled it, but did you configured visual studio to actually support it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installing-python-support-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt yea I reinstalled with that purpose